# twitter Bootstrap Scrollspy highlight final element

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a single page website with the top bar navigation linking to different sections on the page. I've linked it up using [Scrollspy](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy) as  `<body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="50" id="home">`. That works great. Each section is highlighted in the navigation.

The problem lies with the final section. Because it is a short section and does not fill the entire page the `id="contact"` is never reached, and therefore the navigation element is not highlighted.

I notice that on the [bootstrap examples page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel) when you reach the final element it is highlighted before its `id` is reached - yet the `id` is at the top of the section just like all the other sections.

I've had a look through the custom `application.js` file but don't see anything relating to scrollspy behaviour.

Can anyone shed any light on it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was just looking for the answer to this myself. The bootstrap demo page was definitely doing something different than my page when it came to the last item. I too looked through application.js but didn't see anything. Finally I decided to compare their version of scrollspy.js and mine. They are using v2.0.4 while I had v2.0.2. I replaced my version with the new and it just started working as expected.

Then I referred to the bootstrap changelog and found out that v2.0.3 was released on April 24, 2012. One of the changes listed was "Always select last item in scrollspy if you've reached the bottom of the document or element".

So I guess they quietly fixed it internally since I downloaded bootstrap. You may have already figured this out too, but hopefully it will help others looking for the same answer.

Comment: Hi Jon, no I hand't figured it out. I was just experimenting and it fell by the wayside. You've got the answer though so thanks for pointing it out, I'll look forward to using it in a project in the future.

Answer (score 11):

For some this issue could be due to a quirks/DOCTYPE issue.  If your scroll area is on the body, then scrollspy will calculate viewport height off of the window object. If you are using jQuery 1.8.2 and you do not have the proper DOCTYPE set, then the scrollspy calculation for viewport height will return the total height causing the last item to always be selected.

If you switch back to jQuery 1.7.2 like on http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html then it will work again, or you can set the proper DOCTYPE.

Here is more info on the "notabug" issue : http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12426

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem... don't know how I left the doctype off doh!

Comment: Adding a <!DOCTYPE html> instead of older <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http: //www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> helped me!

Answer (score 5):

Just increase your `data-offset` attribute to something larger like `500`, like so:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="500" id="home">
```

The bootstrap demo works fine because it is also offsetting the height of the subnav, along with the `50px` offset that is given on the data attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I believe there's some higher forces at play than just the data-offset though. The final section on the twitter example definitely behaves differently. Plus, increasing the offset in my example causes problems if there are smaller sections (example updated).

Comment: @deadlyhifi your demo works fine for me, i also exported it to jsfiddle and it also works there just fine with the data-offset of 500, http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/cBPgB/5/show/

Comment: Thanks for looking into this - the demo isn't quite right. If you have the browser full width and click on 'Cheesehead' it will take you to that section but the highlighted element is 'Contact'. On the twitter example the final section definitely behaves differently to the other sections.

Answer (score 3):

I have a workaround. On line 40 of twitter's scrollspy JS, you'll see:

```
this.process()
```

Just remove that. This runs the process method in a clever attempt to start 'er up. But this is processed when you scroll anyways, so just remove it and you should be good.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the HTML doctype declaration to the top of the page fixed it for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Crazy, this was driving me up the wall. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case it only works if I set the scrollable data container to the `<body>` element.

I use a smooth scroll script combined with it and it works great:

```
$('.sub-nav-collapse .nav li a').live('click',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top-70}, 500);
});
```

Hope that helps someone!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery 1.8.3 and an html5 doctype, I found that having a viewport initial scale of 1 caused scrollspy to fail:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I removed the reference to initial-scale=1 and scrollspy started working.

Comment: Adding maximum-scale=1 to meta viewport fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this question looking for solution for my problem. Scrollspy worked fine until it reached last 4 sections. When it happened it jumped immediately to the last sections avoiding 3 others on his way. It was caused by relatively small sizes of those sections. Thanks to Jon's answer I decided to investigate scrollspy script and I found the following lines:

```
if (scrollTop >= maxScroll) {
    return activeTarget != (i = targets.last()[0])
    && this.activate ( i )
}
```

They are responsible to select last section if the end of page is reached. Commenting them may help in cases like mine (jumping 3 sections at once), but it prevents from reaching the last section if it is to small.